# lftp mirror wrong return code

Tags: sftp, lftp

I am using lftp mirror -R to sync a local dir to a remote sftp dir

Just to get myself super clarified, the script my i am running `lftp -f` is 
as follows

```
open sftp://hostname port
user username password
mirror -R local_dir sftp_dir
exit
```

However I keep getting exit code 1 from `mirror -R`,even though from the standard stdout it seem that it has successfully uploaded the file and I can verify that the files are indeed upload from sftp.

So just wondering why is that happening and how i can get correct exit code

Comment: Log file? Stdout dump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-zero exit code without error messages means that something has silently failed. Most often it is "chmod" operation. Try adding --no-perms option. To be sure, enable debug and see the interaction with the server.